# Translate javascript time function to php

Tags: javascript, php

I have an working javascript code that i use on an webpage to set text of an button.
The text of the button show the time in 24 hour format with added 1 hour and 30 minutes rounded of to nearest 5 minutes. 
As i need to use the resulting time in an php code snippet on button click i need to convert my code to php syntax to get the same result.

As example if time now is 15:17 the result should be 16:50

```
<SCRIPT>
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(today.getHours() + 1);
    today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 30);
    var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    var date = "09:07:00";  //or use any other date
    var rounded = new Date(Math.round(today.getTime() / coeff) * coeff)
    var tid_1hour30min_from_now = rounded.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
    var tid_hour = rounded.getHours();
    var tid_minutes = rounded.getMinutes();
    var ater = "Åter"
    var result1hour30minfromnow = ater +" "+ tid_1hour_from_now
</SCRIPT>
```

So i would like to do the same but in php.

Been trying with simular code to this:

```
$startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1,5 
hour',strtotime($startTime)));

$current_time = strtotime($cenvertedTime);

$frac = 900;
$r = $current_time % $frac;

$new_time = $current_time + ($frac-$r);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d g:i:s A', $new_time);
```

But this doesn't turn out well, i newer get the same time in both script above.
How can i translate the javascript as close as possible to php?

/ Kristian

Comment: Is none of the answers what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with "normal" date() function also.

```
$startTime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))+90*60; // add 90 minutes times 60 seconds to UNIX time.
$NewMinute = round(date("i", $startTime)/5)*5; // find new minute by rounding on "5"

echo date("Y-m-d H:", $startTime) .str_pad($NewMinute, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

https://3v4l.org/fkGbQ

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I like your sugestion but i'm having problem when the $NewMinute is just one digit, example 90 minutes from now is 10:05 $NewMinute would be 5 and not 05 is it would need to be.

Comment: @Kristian added str_pad to the output

Answer (score 0):

So if you want the same time value of your button in the php script on button click then you can simply send the time value using ajax to the php file

To use JQuery plugin include below line

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

then use below code to send time value using ajax to php file on button click

```
var btn_date = $('#btn_id').text();
$.ajax({
    url: "phpfile.php",
    type: "post",
    data: "date_val="+btn_date,
    success: function(data) {
            $('.status_text').html(data);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the code correctly you want to add 1 hour and 30 minutes to the current time. You can do this quite easily with the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects.
The following code adds 1 1/2 hour to the current time and outputs the hour(24) and minutes.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new \DateInterval("PT1H30M")); // add 1,5 hour
$date->format("H:i");
```

If you want other formats take a look at the [date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help from Andreas :)
    `//get the time one hour from now rounded off to nearest 5 minute
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); //Set timezone
    $startTime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))+30*60;
    $NewMinute = round(date("i", $startTime)/5)*5;
    $num_padded = sprintf("%02d", $NewMinute);  //When the NewMinute is less than 
    2 digits add leading zero
    $time_to_set = date("H:", $startTime) .$num_padded;`

Comment: So what is the issue with my code that makes you not want to accept it? It does what you ask for and the only thing you have changed is the str_pad vs sprintf. https://3v4l.org/q1XKQ

Comment: Sorry, i'm not used to use stackowerflow :) Thanks for your help!